# Stuck with applying the device tree overlay file (dtbo) On BeagleBoard-XM, any suggestions how?

Tags: beagleboard, gpio, firmware, device-tree

I have recently took my Beagleboard-xM (Rev B) and put on it the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (3.14.2-armv7-x5),
then I tried to mux Pin3 (GPIO_139), after reading thoroughly the pages from both the "System Reference Manual"(Page 110) and the "Technical Reference Manual" of the processor (Pages 2444-2453).
So I wrote the dts file and compiled it via dtc.

but now I got stuck . how do I apply the changes on runtime?

I saw on the beaglebone there is a slots file (/sys/devices/.../slots) which was triggering the change,
after we echoed to it the dtbo file. but in my case we are talking about beagleboard-xM which there is no such kind of file.
can someone elaborate what should I do?

Any suggestion would be great! thank you all.

Gil

Comment: HI @JammingThebBits I'm also facing the same issue.. Any updates on this problem?

Comment: Not yet. I'll update you in the future, had no time to work on this issue.

Comment: Hi @JammingThebBits , I've now managed to learn how to modify the dts file and convert it into dtb for booting kernel. that helps me now. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you elaborate on modifying the dts file?